# My search bar prints every variable instead of just the one you typed

Tags: python-3.x

My search bar wont work

I am making an encyclopedia for superheroes and i am currently working on the search bar.

```py
for x in range(1, 2):
    choose_hero = input("Select your hero:  ")
    superhero_batman = print("real name: Bruce Wayne has no powers is in DC universe")
    superhero_antman = print("real name:Scott lang powers: suit enables him to change size and communicate with some insects like ants universe is Marvel")
    superhero_hulk = print("real name: Bruce Banner powers super strength can leap miles can sonic clap universe is Marvel")
    heroes = ['superhero_batman', 'superhero_antman', 'superhero_hulk']
    hero = input("Select your item: ")
if choice in heroes:
    print(hero)
else:
    print("unidentified")
```

when you type a hero on the list it prints every single superhero on there instead of only printing the one you typed. how do i make it only print the one you typed?

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to achieve, I'd suggest you use a **dictionary**.

```
hero_info = {
    "batman": "real name: Bruce Wayne has no powers is in DC universe",
    "antman": "real name:Scott lang powers: suit enables him to change size and communicate with some insects like ants universe is Marvel"
    ...
}
```

now you can acess the information in the dictonary with the name of your desired hero in square brackets, like this:

```
print(hero_info["batman"])
>>> real name: Bruce Wayne has no powers is in DC universe
```

A full program could look something like this:

```
hero_info = {
    "batman": "real name: Bruce Wayne has no powers is in DC universe",
    "antman": "real name:Scott lang powers: suit enables him to change size and communicate with some insects like ants universe is Marvel"
    ...
}

choose_hero = input("Select your hero: ")

if choose_hero in hero_info:
    print(hero_info[choose_hero])
else:
    print("This hero is not in my database.")
```